# What's the right way to use custom exceptions in Restler?

Tags: php, restler

Lets say insted of just output:

```
{
  "error": 
  {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Some internal error"
  }
}
```

I would like to output:

```
{
  "error": 
  {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Some internal error",
    "error_code" : 1050
  }
}
```

Also is there a way we can catch all the exceptions for log purposes for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RestException to throw the exception and use the details parameter (an array) to add additional details

```
throw new RestException(400, 'invalid user', array('error_code' => 12002));
```

gives me the following

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request: invalid user",
    "error_code": 12002
  },
  "debug": {
    "source": "Say.php:5 at call stage",
    "stages": {
      "success": [
        "get",
        "route",
        "negotiate",
        "validate"
      ],
      "failure": [
        "call",
        "message"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Info:-** additional debug information is returned when restler is running in debug mode.
It can be turned off by using `Compose::$includeDebugInfo=false;`

**Note:-** Make sure you are using Restler 3.0 RC4 or higher

Comment: also is there an easy way to log the exceptions for debug purposes? Lets say I want to find bad calls in my app, its much easier to log everything from the api

Comment: You can write your own compose class using the iCompose interface and log the exceptions from there